# Adding a second tableofcontents with alphabetical order and only subsections

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I'm creating a songbook in LaTeX and want to have two tables of contents: 1st with regular section order, 2nd with alphabetical order and only subsections (individual songs).

I have songs in subsections and categories of songs in sections done this way to hide the section title because it's in header (done with \markboth)

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Songs A Category}

\newpage
\subsection{F_Song}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\subsection{C_Song}
\lipsum[1]

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Songs B Category}
\newpage
\subsection{A_Song}
\lipsum[1]
```

Then I just do `\tableofcontents` to get my regular table of contents that looks like:

```
Songs A category 10
    F_Song 10
    C_Song 11
Songs B Category 12
    A_Song 12
```

and I want an additional one that looks like:

```
A_Song 12
C_Song 11
F_Song 10
```

I saw some solutions for that but all of them were not sufficient because of the need for two tables. If needed I know Python and will be able to generate some script to reorder the additional toc file but I still wouldn't know how to make a second table out of it.